# JSP auto-deploy not work on Spring/JPA project with Eclipse and Liberty

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp, deployment, websphere-liberty

I work with a Spring 4 project on Eclipse and IBM Liberty as Application server. Well, every minimal JSP edit I have to restart the whole server and it take almost 3 minutes.
Application is an EAR container with seven web projects (only one is spring) and others java libraries

Auto deploy is configured, indeed all java class editing is immediatly deployed.

anyone know as extending auto deploing to jsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you mentioned which Liberty features you have enabled on your server.  Regardless, I think I know the answer.  You most likely have either javaee-7.0 or at least cdi-1.2 enabled...or some other feature that requires cdi-1.2.

The issue you are describing sounds a lot like the issue fixed in APAR PI58316:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI58316

During a JSP request, your Spring jar(s) are likely causing the JSP request processing to invoke the cdi-1.2 code which had this problem.  This resulted in changes to a JSP file to not show up on a new request...the server had to be restarted. You would not see this issue with a very simple JSP project that did not contain Spring or other code that would have a dependency on CDI.  Also, this issue is specific to a JSP request, which is why you see your other Java class editing being reloaded without any issue.
 This issue is now fixed with APAR PI58316 which is included in WebSphere Liberty fixpack 16.0.0.2.  I would recommend that you upgrade to that level to see if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Thank. I've found the problem... the Liberty 8 version have a bug!. See the answer below

Comment: This is the same bug I pointed you to in my answer back on July 27th.  Yet you did not accept my answer as resolving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! I found this is a bug of WebSphere Liberty 8 version.
On Liberty new version (16) there is a fix.

See this link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI58316

Here another topic of this problem [Websphere liberty profile jsp changes are not reflected using Spring data jpa library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608002/websphere-liberty-profile-jsp-changes-are-not-reflected-using-spring-data-jpa-li)